# What is the facebook app settings for Phonegap's facebook-plugin?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, android-facebook

Im trying to build an Android Phonegap application with facebook-plugin.

This is my eclipse's project tree:

[image: My porject tree]

and this is the FB app settings form:

did i fill it correct?
[image: FB app settings]

Comment: did you get a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I've built for Facebook but I'm pretty sure that the 'Package Name' needs to be your main package that the app is known by - so in your AndroidManifest.xml it will be whatever the value is for `package=...`. Then the Class Name is the name of the class that you want to launch from Facebook. The little [?] seems to indicate that this can be any class.

You might want to change Package Name to `com.tech.map` and Class Name to `org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin`....but I'm really not positive. Maybe either will work. Based on my reading of the ConnectPlugin readme, I'm not even sure that you need to do this; it looks like all you need is an APP_ID which can be found at the top of the "dashboard" page for your app.